# Замена текста ссылки на текст из input

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, почему **[не работает скрипт](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/rcaRB/)**.

И еще, как сделать, чтобы при открытии блока с `<input type="text" />`, поле становилось активным.

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Поправил работу фокуса и изменение значения](http://jsfiddle.net/rcaRB/2/).

```
// change text
    $('.change-text').click(function() {
        var that = this;
        var textFieldBox = $(this).next();
        var textField = $(this).next().find('input[type="text"]'); // правильный селектор

        if (textFieldBox.css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).addClass('change-text-active');
            textFieldBox.css('display', 'block');
            textField.focus(); // устанавливаем фокус
        }

        textField.keydown(function(eventObject) {
          if(eventObject.which == 13) {
            var value = textField.val();
            textFieldBox.css('display', 'none');
            $(that).text(value);
            $(this).removeClass('change-text-active');
          }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Из нерабочего то, что текст ссылки не заменяется на значение  из поля.

Comment: Посмотрите, я поправил еще раз.

Comment: Теперь все работает. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Zhukov Roman. Роман, а подскажите пожалуйста еще, как к keydown добавить и другие события, например потеря фокуса.

Спасибо.